# CellForRow(at:IndexPath) works only for visible cells

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

`CellForRow(at:IndexPath)` function works only when the cells are visible or about to be visible. This was working fine for a few weeks but yesterday it stopped working.
I want to extract data from multiple textfields in a cell on the press of a save button.
I would like any solutions to resolving this or would also consider a different approach to this particular problem

Used `CellForRow`  function to get the cell at a specific index.
was working fine for a few days. Now it returns nil if the cell is not visible.

Comment: why you going to extract data from cells ? why not from model that you should have to use to populate tableview and extract data from model ?

Comment: Cells are not data models, data should be stored in your models and passed to the cells, not the other way around. As text fields update, you should update your models.

Comment: That is the expected behaviour .```CellForRow(at:IndexPath)``` returns ```nil``` for non-visible cells in versions lower than ```iOS 15```.  For newer versions it will return a non-nil cell. Solution would be on textfield's  ```textFieldDidEndEditing``` add the texts in to an array.

Comment: If I want to extract information added to a textfield in a cell, how would i proceed to do that?
and also the main question was it was working fine uptill now

Comment: Even on iOS 16 cellForRow might return nil. The algorithm for pre-fetching and reusing cells changed so the table view might hold on to a cell even when it is not visible. But this should not be relied on. You should not be using cells as a data store. When the textfields finish editing you should pass information from the cell to the view controller so it can update its data model. The same data model you use in cellForRow when creating cells.

Comment: *…was working fine for a few days.* No, never, `cellForRow(at:` returns `nil` for invisible cells since `iOS 1`. And *invisible* is actually the wrong term. A cell is being detached from its index path when going off screen.

Comment: why he is using a view to get value of textfield why not go for a model that are using for populating the tableview so after updating the text in textfield the model get updated with text and then get info from model not from a view/cell that is dequeuereuseable... ?

Comment: I have decided to use the textFieldDidEndEditing to get the value and save it somewhere